# Are both cameras easily accesible on the HTC EVO 3D?

Tags: android, 3d, stereo-3d, htcsense

We are considering developing an application for the HTC EVO 3D that will be used in a laboratory setting, and we need to know if it is possible to control both cameras on the hardware.

Does the SDK provide easy access (or *any* access) to both of the stereo cameras on the HTC EVO? If so, what code would be required to manipulate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the cameras do not have individual access. It is indicated in the developer portal (http://htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/stereoscopic-3d) of HTC as follows:

> Camera selection:
>
> - Camera 0 = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK (as of Android 2.3)
> - Camera 1 = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT (as of Android 2.3)
> - Camera 2 = undefined in Android platform, HTC specific value for stereoscopic camera mode (both rear facing cameras)
>
> so the equivalent to the hardware 3D-2D switch for the camera mode would be to switch between camera selections 0 (also the default) and 2:

So, I'm afraid the cameras could not be accessed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Stereoscopic Camera mode has recently changed (with ICS Android 4 update) from a value of 2 to 100